# Should I backup my htdocs content before xampp reinstall?

Tags: xampp

I am using `xampp 5.6.3`. Now I am planning to install `xampp 5.6.14`. And I have many projects in my `htdocs` folder. If I reinstall `xampp`, will it contents inside `htdocs` remain or will they be overwritten? Is there any way to reinstall `xampp` and keep my projects safe?

**UPDATE**

All project related databases are in`mysql`. Will those things get deleted too?

Comment: Also take a sql dump of the database?

Comment: @RyanVincent Thanks for remind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A database `dump` is a must, htdocs folder will remain after you uninstall xampp but you might replace it on re installation.So I strongly recommend you `not` to take the chance. Always take a backup. may be a `tar/zip` of the `htdocs` folder before uninstalling.

See this [answer](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=175337&sid=a967302060247a9ab52447604fa625f6) for a step by step answer on reinstalling xampp.

Answer (score 0):

The "answer" you point to for advice on reinstalling xampp goes here:

"Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /f/viewtopic.php on this server."

Everything about apachefriends and xampp forums is "forbidden", no help anywhere.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31736090)